# txt file as input to deserialise the data in protobuff python, not able to read data in proper format

Tags: python, decode

I want to use the text file as input to the `ParseFromString()` function in protobuff
data that is stored inside text file as shown below:

this is protobuff serialised data

```
0363D1015F5402656E0A140A0410021801120C120A303132333435363738390A0A0A0410071802120218020A120A04103A1819120A3A080A020001100220010A0A0A04103A1862120230000A140A0410081864120C420A082810591801204428448436B57E
```

i want data to be in this format as input to deserialise the data

```
b'\x03h\xd1\x01dT\x02en\n\x19\n\x04\x10\x02\x18\x01\x12\x11\x12\x0f50D50U-843-01B1\n\n\n\x04\x10\x07\x18\x02\x12\x02\x18\x02\n\x12\n\x04\x10:\x18\x10\x12\n:\x08\n\x02\x00\x01\x10\x02 \x01\n\n\n\x04\x10;\x18(\x12\x020\x00\n\x14\n\x04\x10:\x18a\x12\x0cB\n\x08(\x10Y\x18\x01 D(Dj\xdec\xd6'
```

but when i read text file as binary i am getting data like this, so not able to deserialise the data in protobuff

```
b'\xff\xfe0\x003\x006\x003\x00D\x001\x000\x001\x005\x00F\x005\x004\x000\x002\x006\x005\x006\x00E\x000\x00A\x001\x004\x000\x00A\x000\x004\x001\x000\x000\x002\x001\x008\x000\x001\x001\x002\x000\x00C\x001\x002\x000\x00A\x003\x000\x003\x001\x003\x002\x003\x003\x003\x004\x003\x005\x003\x006\x003\x007\x003\x008\x003\x009\x000\x00A\x000\x00A\x000\x00A\x000\x004\x001\x000\x000\x007\x001\x008\x000\x002\x001\x002\x000\x002\x001\x008\x000\x002\x000\x00A\x001\x002\x000\x00A\x000\x004\x001\x000\x003\x00A\x001\x008\x001\x009\x001\x002\x000\x00A\x003\x00A\x000\x008\x000\x00A\x000\x002\x000\x000\x000\x001\x001\x000\x000\x002\x002\x000\x000\x001\x000\x00A\x000\x00A\x000\x00A\x000\x004\x001\x000\x003\x00A\x001\x008\x006\x002\x001\x002\x000\x002\x003\x000\x000\x000\x000\x00A\x001\x004\x000\x00A\x000\x004\x001\x000\x000\x008\x001\x008\x006\x004\x001\x002\x000\x00C\x004\x002\x000\x00A\x000\x008\x002\x008\x001\x000\x005\x009\x001\x008\x000\x001\x002\x000\x004\x004\x002\x008\x004\x004\x008\x004\x003\x006\x00B\x005\x007\x00E\x00'
```

I am using python 3
how can i read text file data as i required?

Comment: would you mind show your code for serialization and save?
your file starts with `"\xff\xfe"`, that's a utf8 BOM header (usually on windows), I guess you are saving it in text mode, or some other transform glitches.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code snippet (*explained in commens*):

```
xb = b'\xff\xfe0\x003\x006\x003\x00D\x001\x000\x001\x005\x00F\x005\x004\x000\x002\x006\x005\x006\x00E\x000\x00A\x001\x004\x000\x00A\x000\x004\x001\x000\x000\x002\x001\x008\x000\x001\x001\x002\x000\x00C\x001\x002\x000\x00A\x003\x000\x003\x001\x003\x002\x003\x003\x003\x004\x003\x005\x003\x006\x003\x007\x003\x008\x003\x009\x000\x00A\x000\x00A\x000\x00A\x000\x004\x001\x000\x000\x007\x001\x008\x000\x002\x001\x002\x000\x002\x001\x008\x000\x002\x000\x00A\x001\x002\x000\x00A\x000\x004\x001\x000\x003\x00A\x001\x008\x001\x009\x001\x002\x000\x00A\x003\x00A\x000\x008\x000\x00A\x000\x002\x000\x000\x000\x001\x001\x000\x000\x002\x002\x000\x000\x001\x000\x00A\x000\x00A\x000\x00A\x000\x004\x001\x000\x003\x00A\x001\x008\x006\x002\x001\x002\x000\x002\x003\x000\x000\x000\x000\x00A\x001\x004\x000\x00A\x000\x004\x001\x000\x000\x008\x001\x008\x006\x004\x001\x002\x000\x00C\x004\x002\x000\x00A\x000\x008\x002\x008\x001\x000\x005\x009\x001\x008\x000\x001\x002\x000\x004\x004\x002\x008\x004\x004\x008\x004\x003\x006\x00B\x005\x007\x00E\x00'
xs = xb.decode('utf-16') # \xff\xfe signature in xb => apply UTF-16
print('xs:', xs)
xx = bytes.fromhex(xs)   # all hexadecimal ciphers in xs
print('xx:', xx)
```

**Result**: `.\SO\65987622.py`

```
xs: 0363D1015F5402656E0A140A0410021801120C120A303132333435363738390A0A0A0410071802120218020A120A04103A1819120A3A080A020001100220010A0A0A04103A1862120230000A140A0410081864120C420A082810591801204428448436B57E
xx: b'\x03c\xd1\x01_T\x02en\n\x14\n\x04\x10\x02\x18\x01\x12\x0c\x12\n0123456789\n\n\n\x04\x10\x07\x18\x02\x12\x02\x18\x02\n\x12\n\x04\x10:\x18\x19\x12\n:\x08\n\x02\x00\x01\x10\x02 \x01\n\n\n\x04\x10:\x18b\x12\x020\x00\n\x14\n\x04\x10\x08\x18d\x12\x0cB\n\x08(\x10Y\x18\x01 D(D\x846\xb5~'
```

Comment: this is working for me thanks for the response.